# find the vector with the largest size among group of vectors c++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Given a vector of vectors, I want to find the vector with the laregest size, and I use the following code:

```
 bool Longest(vector<int> &A, vector<int> &B){
       return A.size()>B.size();
 }
 vector<vector<int> >::iterator max_itr= max_element(L.begin(),L.end(),Longest);
```

where L is a vector of vectors (`vector<vector<int> >`)

I keep getting the iterator point to the L.begin(). Any suggestions?

Comment: From [this `std::max_element` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) regarding the comparison function: "returns ​true if the first argument is less than the second". So maybe you should reverse the condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison functor object passed to [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) should return `true` if the first operand is *less* than the second one. Your comparison has this the wrong way around. You need

```
bool Longest(const vector<int> &A, const vector<int> &B)
{
   return A.size() < B.size();
}
```

Also note that it is better for the parameters to be `const` references because the comparison operation should not modify its operands.

---

Here's a [**working example**](http://ideone.com/ZRRiAt).